# Проблема с подключением google-play-services_lib

Tags: java, android, google-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с подобной ситуацией!

Скачал пример: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/banner-adlistener

Подключил google-play-services_lib как учат: http://hmkcode.com/adding-google-play-services-library-to-your-android-app/

Начинаю запускать Run AS, eclipse пишет

> Launching ….

и так этот процесс весит продолжительное время пока принудительно не закроешь eclipse через панель задач.
Т.е.  APK не компилируется и эмулятор не запускается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо создавать эмулятор с поддержкой Google Services. В дефолтном эмуляторе нет поддержки сервисов Google.

Во время создания эмулятора, надо выбирать в поле target:

> Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API level XX

Comment: или поставить genymotion, но все равно надо будет патчить для ГС

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!!!

Answer (score 0):

Может путь к папке  далекий. Попробуй перемести библиотеку по ближе.